# WEKA classes in map and reduce phases of KMeans Clustering on hadoop

Tags: mapreduce, cluster-analysis, weka, k-means, euclidean-distance

I want to use WEKA's classes inside mapreduce program for performing KMeans Clustering on Instances. I just want an overview for map and reduce classes. How the distance computed by WEKA classes be reviewed in Reducer classes?

Answer (score 1):

Short story is: you can't.

If you want a map-reduce algorithm, it needs to be *designed* as such.

There is no push-button solution that allows you to parallelize all of Wekas code to map-reduce. Otherwise, we would all be running map-reduce for everything.

It literally would need to be **rewritten from scratch** to fully run on Mapreduce.